# Must I get Length of List first and then query List in Redis?

Tags: redis

I wanna know if only `lrange` could get a List in `Redis`? It needs the `end` parameter, and if I wanna the full List, I must use `llen` to get the length first. Like this:

```
redis.lrange("myList", 0, llen("myList"));
```

Whether there's any method can get a full List directly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use -1 as an index of last element. This will get you the whole list:

```
lrange mylist 0 -1
```

And this will get whole list but the last element

```
lrange mylist 0 -2
```

And so forth...

By the way, it's all written [in the documentation](http://redis.io/commands/lrange).